# Are there infinitely many palindromes whose sum is a perfect square?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, palindrome

I am just curious on wether there are infinitely many palindromes say $p_1$ and $p_2$ satisfying:

$p_1^2+p_2^2$ is a perfect square with $\gcd(p_1,p_2)=1$.

I believe that there are some but, are there infinitely many of them?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So far, I only found the pairs $(3/4)$ and $(464/777)$

Comment: Thanks peter, I suspect that there are only finite of them, but a general proof still awaits.

Comment: I actually want to prove my claim, but I dont know how to.

Comment: Does the pair $(0/1)$ also count ?

Comment: No peter, we start at 1.

Comment: Perhaps, it helps studying the primitive pythagorean triples.

Comment: There are no more pairs for $p_1,p_2\le 10\ 000$

Comment: Better let us delete unnecessary posts.

Comment: Google *palindromic pythagorean triple*.

Comment: I tried but again it did not help. Thanks Lucian

Comment: A spectacular pair is $(5679765/23711732)$

Comment: It's in the list at the link in my answer.

Comment: We can try, but I do not know if it works. I found the pair by constructing primitive pythagorean triples and checking, if they are also palindromic.

Comment: Peter, I also tried that, what computer software are you using? My conjecture is there are only finite of them

Comment: I use PARI/GP, a nice computational tool.

Comment: I see, It is actually my first time to hear that tool and how is it compared to mathematica, is it okay with you peter if you give me some updates if you have time? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there are infinitely many. For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let
$$\begin{align}
a_n&=3+4\times10^{n}+7\times10^{2n}+4\times10^{3n}+3\times10^{4n}\\
b_n&=4+2\times10^{n}+8\times10^{2n}+2\times10^{3n}+4\times10^{4n}\\
c_n&=5+4\times10^{n}+11\times10^{2n}+4\times10^{3n}+5\times10^{4n}
\end{align}$$
Then $a_n$ and $b_n$ are palindromes and 
$$
a_n^2+b_n^2=c_n^2.
$$
Moreover, $\gcd(a_n,b_n)=1$. Let
$$\begin{align}
A_n&=7+8\times10^{n}+8\times10^{2n}+8\times10^{3n}\\
B_n&=-\frac12\bigl(10+21\times10^{n}+22\times10^{2n}+12\times10^{3n}\bigr)
\end{align}$$
Then
$$
A_n\,a_n+B_n\,b_n=1.
$$

I found this identity doing a brute force search. Any palindrome with an even number of digits is divisible by $11$, so one (or both) of the $p_i$ must have an odd number of digits. I have searched for $p_1$ with $2\,k+1$ digits, $1\le j\le 7$. These are the results. Included are also some examples of $p_1$ with $17$ digits.
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
 313 & 48984 \\
 464 & 777 \\
 25652 & 55755 \\
 34743 & 42824 \\
 52625 & 80808 \\
 80308 & 5578755 \\
 2152512 & 575575 \\
 2532352 & 5853585 \\
 5679765 & 23711732 \\
 304070403 & 402080204 \\
 341484143 & 420282024 \\
 345696543 & 422282224 \\
 355949553 & 690019910096 \\
 359575953 & 401141104 \\
 27280108272 & 55873637855 \\
 3004007004003 & 4002008002004 \\
 3044529254403 & 4022208022204 \\
 3410048400143 & 4200028200024 \\
 3414249424143 & 4202028202024 \\
 3450569650543 & 4224448444224 \\
 6381414141836 & 778233332877 \\
 395734505437593 & 426982282289624 \\
 404990565099404 & 747709181907747 \\
 461781161187164 & 778676101676877 \\
 30004000700040003 & 40002000800020004 \\
 30040410801404003 & 40020200800202004 \\
 30044412921444003 & 40022200800222004 \\
 30081842624818003 & 40041401210414004 \\
 30401040804010403 & 40200020802000204 \\
 30405060906050403 & 40202020802020204 \\
 32682698889628623 & 46020004840002064 \\
 34100004840000143 & 42000002820000024 \\
 34104204940240143 & 42002002820020024 \\
 34140434943404143 & 42024404840442024 \\
 34505056965050543 & 42244646864644224 \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot Prof., if it is okay with you sir, can we have a detailed discussion about this topic? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Prof. If I am allowed can I have your email address? Here is mine jrantalan@clsu.edu.ph

Comment: Prof. I had already sent an email. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Following Lucian's hint, I found a list of them at http://www.worldofnumbers.com/pythago.htm but many of the ones listed there fail the relative primality test. But not all: $313^2+48984^2=48985^2$, $34743^2+42824^2=55145^2$, probably a few others that I didn't test for relative primality.

Comment: Thanks Sir Jerry, I also tried to look at it and notice that there are some. But, my conjecture is: there are only finite of them, And I am seeking for help to prove my conjecture.

Comment: What makes you think there are only finitely many?

Comment: Its because of scarcity of numbers that satisfies this as an integer $n$ goes large sir. Lacking of computer softwares is a hindrance about my conjecture sir.

Comment: But you don't know for a fact that the numbers are scarce. I don't think you have even looked at the table in the link to see how many are there.

Comment: I tried sir, some of them are not relatively prime. The list at the site are still few,a super computer might help to verify or disprove my claim. Unfortunately I dont have it.

Comment: You need a theory, not a computer. A computer can't prove there are infnitely many, and it can't prove there are only finitely many. But maybe if you examine the examples on offer you'll see some patterns.

Comment: Mersenne primes are also scarce, but it is believed that there are inifinitely many.

Comment: I agree with you sir, understand now, I indeed need a theory. If ever sirs I update you if I have and Is it okay with you sirs to verify my claims?

Comment: FYI: Fifteen of the thirty-nine triples on the World of Numbers page are relatively prime: $(3, 4, 5)$,
$(464, 777, 905)$,
$(313, 48984, 48985)$,
$(34743, 42824, 55145)$,
$(25652, 55755, 61373)$,
$(52625, 80808, 96433)$,
$(575575, 2152512, 2228137)$,
$(80308, 5578755, 5579333)$,
$(2532352, 5853585, 6377873)$,
$(5679765, 23711732, 24382493)$,
$(304070403, 402080204, 504110405)$,
$(341484143, 420282024, 541524145)$,
$(345696543, 422282224, 545736545)$,
$(359575953, 401141104, 538710545)$,
$(27280108272, 55873637855, 62177710753)$

Comment: Thanks blue, If ever you find others can you update me? Thank you again,